# FPDF Converting Apostrophes into Weird Characters

Tags: special-characters, decode, fpdf, apostrophe

I have this string passed from a JavaScript form:
    4 H/M’s

Which gets posted to an array, called '$out' and is keyed by "blurb".

I use FPDF to output it, with MultiCell, like so:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(190,4,$out["blurb"]);
```

However, FPDF outputs this string:

```
4 H/Mâ€™s
```

I've tried

```
html_entity_decode($out["blurb"], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use iconv like this :

```php
// put $str your sting to encode for FPDF
// put $myencoding value as you current encoding
function fpdf_encode($str,$myencoding='latin1') { 
  return iconv($myencoding, 'windows-1252', trim(utf8_decode($str)));
}
```